# How to delay component rendering when response from the server is delayed

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am a newbie to react. I have a situation where in I am fetching some data from the server which I want to display in a page. I am using websockets for communication between the client and server. As the server makes a request to some third party API the response gets delayed. But my component gets rendered before the response comes. I have seen answers which talks about handling such situation in case of ajax request. But how do i handle it in the case of web sockets. My sample jsx page which I want to render after getting response from server is as follows

```
import React ,{PureComponent} from 'react';

    export default class ScorePanel extends PureComponent{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            var d = new Date();
            this.currentDate = d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+ "-"+ d.getDate();
            this.week ="1";
            this.numQuarters =1;
        }
        getInitialState(){
             return {
                 resultsObtianed: false
              }
         }
        getScores(){
            return this.props.scores ||[];
        }
        render() {

            return <div className = 'scorePanel'>
                     if ( !this.state.response ) {
                          return <div>loging response</div>
                    }
                    {
                        // data to render after geting response from server
                    }
    }
```

How do I let the client know that response from the server has been received and it's time to render a component. It would be better if I can show a loading page if the response gets delayed. So I would like to make use of getInitialState function as well. I am dispatching an action to the server on a button click in the navigation bar. Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a websocket ws, and listening to "test" event.
in your oncomponentDidMount do

```html
componentDidMount()
{
  ws.on("test",(data)=>{
    this.setState({response:data})
  })
}
```

also I like to predefine state, so I'd add this.state={response:{}} in constructor